# Join or ask to Join meeting in outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I recently joined a team where there were a couple of recurring meetings that the team already set up. Is there an easy way for me to ask to be added to these meetings?

Comment: It’s interesting you say, “joined a team.” Office 365 business users can use Microsoft Teams for this exact purpose. You literally can join the team, at which point all past emails, calendars, files, etc. become available. You don’t mention if you are an Office 365 business user, but that is the predominant service used with Outlook.

Comment: I think I am. But my company might not be using that particular feature.

Comment: It might be worth passing the information on to the powers that be. Office 365 is a rich eco-system of applications that can improve collaboration. Creating a team is one of those.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to join a meeting without an invitation.

You will need to ask your colleagues that organized these meetings to send you
the invitation.

If their calendars are visible to you, or if there is a common calendar,
you can find out whom to ask.